# cbind a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have a `list` of 3 `data.frames` (`X`, `Y`, `Z`). Using **BASE R**, I was wondering how I could `cbind` similarly named variables across these data.frames and store them as a list?

For the example below, I want all variable `AA`s across the the 3 data.frames, all variable `BB`s across the the 3 data.frames, and all variable `CC`s the the 3 data.frames be separately `cbind`ed and stored as a list?

***Note:*** names could be anything, and the number of variables could be any number. A function(al) solution is highly appreciated.

```
r <- list( 

X = data.frame(

     AA = c(1,1,1,1,3,2), 
     BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
     CC = c(2,2,3,1,2,1)), 

Y = data.frame(

     AA = c(1,1,1,1,3,2), 
     BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
     CC = c(2,2,3,1,2,1)),

Z = data.frame(

     AA = c(1,1,1,1,3,2), 
     BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
     CC = c(2,2,3,1,2,1)))
```

Comment: Do each of `X`, `Y`, `Z` have all of `AA`, `BB` and `CC` always ?

Comment: @RonakShah, let's take `X`as the *reference data.frame*, thus we can say all other data.frames should include, among other names, the names in `X`

Comment: Not sure but maybe this? `lapply(r, function(x) merge(x, r[[1]]))` This assumes `x` as the ref and merges?

Comment: @NelsonGon, appreciate it, but I think your solution gives a different result it doesn't cbind the similarly named variables. Here we expect a data.farme for the cbinded variable `AA`, `BB`, and `CC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way using `purrr` and `dplyr` would be to `tranpose` the the list and then `bind_cols` together

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

transpose(r) %>% map(bind_cols)

#$AA
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#      X     Y     Z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     1     1     1
#3     1     1     1
#4     1     1     1
#5     3     3     3
#6     2     2     2

#$BB
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#      X     Y     Z
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     1     1     1
#3     1     1     1
#4     2     2     2
#....
#....
```

---

In base R, taking first dataframe of the list as reference dataframe, we can do

```
all_cols <- names(r[[1]])
#To get common names between all dataframes.
#all_cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(r, names)) 
lapply(all_cols, function(x) sapply(r, `[[`, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we can `cbind` the `list` elements to a single one and then do the `split`

```
m1 <- do.call(cbind, r)
split.default(m1, sub("^.*\\.", "", names(m1)))
```